# How to get the size of an array in lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying get the size of an array and loop in it. I tried use the `getn` function, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
results = 
  {
    address= "Address 1",
    type_address= "RESIDENCIAL",
    phone= "654620460",
    email= "email1@email.com"
  },
  {
    address= "Address 2",
    type_address= "COMERCIAL",
    phone= "604654650",
    email= "email1@email.com"
  }

for i = 0, table.getn(results), 1 do
   if results[i].type_address == "RESIDENCIAL" then
            phone = results[i].phone
            email = results[i].email

            break
        else
            phone = results[1].phone
            email = results[1].email
        end
end

print (phone)
print (email)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the size of the table use `#tbl` for arrays.

You forgot to wrap items into `{}`. For now you assigned `results` to table with `Address 1`, table with `Address 2` is ignored because you didn't assign it to anything (due to mistake)

Wrap it like this:

```lua
results = {
    -- items here
}
```

Quick note: `table.getn` is deprecated and identical to `#tbl`, you can also use
`for k,v in ipairs(results) do`.
Third parameter of `for` statement is optional and defaults to `1`.

```lua
for i = 0, #results do
    if results[i].type_address == "RESIDENCIAL" then
    -- etc
end

-- or
for k, v in ipairs(results) do
    if v.type_address == "RESIDENCIAL" then
    -- etc
end
```

Comment: Lua tables start at 1. So the first loop is `for i = 1, #results do`.

Answer (score 2):

I use...

```
function(len) local incr=0 for _ in pairs(len) do incr=incr+1 end return incr end
```

...as a metamethod `__index.len` for table key counting. Then...

```
> test_table={'1',two='2',pi=math.pi,popen=io.popen}
> setmetatable(test_table,{__index={len=function(len) local incr=0 for _ in pairs(len) do incr=incr+1 end return incr end}})
table: 0x565aa850
> test_table:len()
4
```

...it count mixed numbered and named keys correctly. Where...

```
> #test_table
1
```

...doesnt.

Comment: This is useful for non-sequential tables and non-arrays

Comment: Exactly - Look at the ```arg``` table when you call ```lua -i``` - This table starts with ```0``` and the above code counts it correctly. I am wondering the first times about it that a sequence in Lua dont start with a zero. But in fact a table is more than just an array. Because it can hold almost ( except nil/empty ) everything as a key for a value.